# Relative date filters in drupal views

Tags: drupal-views

Is it possible to use relative date filters as a drupal views filter.

I mean filter on something like registration date = this.fiscal_year

I am playing with it but do not seem to get it to work.

Relative date filters are supported by the api (see also [Relative date filter possible in api?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/31813/relative-date-filter-possible-in-api)) but I have no clue on whether they are also supporter in drupal views, and if not, if it would be difficult to add this functionality.

Comment: Hi Richard, this does really sound like a Drupal Views question, not so much a CiviCRM question. You would potentially be better of asking this question on https://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you tried using conditional filters in Views?

Comment: And/or see this - https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional